# How to show file extensions in finder for all files

Tags: macos, finder

I'm using the Finder Preferences option, but it still won't show the extensions!

Comment: Do you notice any change with some files when you select or deselect the option?

Comment: Well the extensions started showing after a while (I'm not sure if I had to open a new Finder window or not). But either way... its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the files you are wondering about do not have any extension associated with them. Unlike Windows and many other operating systems Mac OS does not require a file extension and can use meta data stored in the filesystem instead.

More about [Resource Fork and File Type/Creator](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/macosx.html).

After some searching around it appears to be [fairly complicated](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=84244) to take information from the meta data and use that to add extension to files.